# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(String) from the type List<Account>

Tags: apex, batch

Below is my code, Not able to understand the reason of getting this error, can I please get some help here.

```java
public class UpdateAccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
        string query = 'select id, Name from Account where Idustry = Agriculture';
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
       
    }
    
    public static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> acclist){
        
        List<Account> acclistToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(Account acc : acclist){
            acc.Name = acc.Name + 'BatchApex';
            
            acclistToUpdate.add('acc');
        }
        
        update acclistToUpdate;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        system.debug('Batch Processed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only put data into a list that's the same type that the list was declared with (or a compatible type).

Your list is a `List<Account>`, a list of `Account`.

While `acc` inside of your loop is an instance of `Account`, what you're trying to put into your list is `'acc'`, a *`String`* literal. A `String` is not an `Account`, and the two types are not compatible, so you get your error. So to address the error, you would change

```
acclistToUpdate.add('acc');
```

to add the Account itself to the list instead (not a string)

```
// Removing the single quotes makes you use the acc variable (a variable of type Account)
acclistToUpdate.add(acc);
```

In this particular case though, you should remove the `acclistToUpdate.add('acc');` line entirely. The Account you're working on is in `acclist`, and if you update the record in the loop, it'll automatically be reflected in `accList` (collections store references to non-primitive types).

+edit:
The theme here is that you would then perform a DML update on `accList` instead of on `acclistToUpdate`

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to change:

```
acclistToUpdate.add('acc');
```

to:

```
acclistToUpdate.add(acc);
```

That said, you are updating every record in `acclist`, so maintaining a separate `acclistToUpdate` variable is redundant. You should just remove it and `update acclist`.